# iOS - How to check if the device is in the same wifi?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, reachability

I already know in iOS 9, We can use HotspotHelper and call supportedNetworkInterfaces() method to get WiFi data like ssid, signalStrength...

But some WiFi may using same ssid, So we can't check if the devices is in the same wifi by compare ssid.

Is there any other way or message from supportedNetworkInterfaces() callback can help us do it?

Comment: I'm dont really know much about iOS programming but cant you do something like a ping? If the device is in the same network you should get a response...